# Custom ExceptionTranslationFilter in spring 4 to handle REST AuthenticationException

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, spring-4

I have a spring MVC RESTful application secured by spring security. Client side is Angular JS.
But my login and logout pages are plain jsp and I do form based login and log out. upon success full authentication, I load my secured  page(it uses anlgularJS and RESTful api).

I need help in handling AuthenticationException & AccessDeniedException  when REST api is called.
I extended ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and I am able to catch AccessDEniedException and throw a json response. 
I understand to handle AuthenticationException ( so I can stop 302 redirection in case of rest full request ) I need to extend ExceptionTranslationFilter. 
Most of the example I found use XML config. But Is it possible to do in Java config ?

I did write a component to extend ExceptionTranslationFilter  and created a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint, But I am not sure, how to inject it into my ExceptionTranslationFilter

I get an error 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationEntryPoint must be specified
I tried adding a constructor, but it thors method not found.
Any help to solve is appreciated.

**MyAuthenticationEntryPoint**

```
@Service
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException arg2)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "Unauthorized.");

    }

}
```

**My ExceptionTranslationFilter**

```
@Component
public class RestExceptionTranslationFilter extends ExceptionTranslationFilter {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestExceptionTranslationFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void sendStartAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain, AuthenticationException reason)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

            boolean isAjax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(req.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));

        if (isAjax) {

            String jsonObject = "{\"message\":\"Please login first.\"," + "\"access-denied\":true,\"cause\":\"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE\"}";
                String contentType = "application/json";
                resp.setContentType(contentType);
                PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
                out.print(jsonObject);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                return;
            }

        super.sendStartAuthentication(req, resp, chain, reason);
    }

}
```

**Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsRepository userDetailsRepository;

    /**
     * In Memory Authentication
     * @param auth
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsRepository);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("Configuring Spring Security HttpSecurity...");
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/app.html").authenticated();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login").loginPage("/login.jsp").defaultSuccessUrl("/app.html").and()
            .authorizeRequests().and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.html").permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public static ExceptionTranslationFilter exceptionTranslationFilter() {
        RestExceptionTranslationFilter exceptionTranslationFilter = new RestExceptionTranslationFilter(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint());
        RestAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandlerImpl = new RestAccessDeniedHandler();
        exceptionTranslationFilter.setAccessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandlerImpl);
        exceptionTranslationFilter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return exceptionTranslationFilter;
    }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - doFilter -
                /org/hmie/fms/sy/myAccount.html at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - doFilter -
                /org/hmie/fms/sy/myAccount.html at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - doFilter -
                /org/hmie/fms/sy/myAccount.html at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - doFilter -
                Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - doFilter -
                /org/hmie/fms/sy/myAccount.html at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.SessionManagementFilter - doFilter -
                Requested session ID CC2CA43BAE60F06F2431C9280A74081F is invalid.
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - doFilter -
                /org/hmie/fms/sy/myAccount.html at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - doFilter -
                /org/hmie/fms/sy/myAccount.html at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - doFilter -
                /org/hmie/fms/sy/myAccount.html at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - matches -
                Checking match of request : '/org/hmie/fms/sy/myaccount.html'; against '/login.jsp'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.270 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - matches -
                Checking match of request : '/org/hmie/fms/sy/myaccount.html'; against '/login'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.286 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - matches -
                Checking match of request : '/org/hmie/fms/sy/myaccount.html'; against '/logout.html'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.286 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - matches -
                Checking match of request : '/org/hmie/fms/sy/myaccount.html'; against '/ess/partials/alertpopup.html'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.286 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - matches -
                Checking match of request : '/org/hmie/fms/sy/myaccount.html'; against '/partials/alertpopup.html'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.287 DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - matches -
                Checking match of request : '/org/hmie/fms/sy/myaccount.html'; against '/fms/**'
2015-01-14_23:10:17.287 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - beforeInvocation -
                Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /org/hmie/fms/sy/myAccount.html; Attributes: [authenticated]
2015-01-14_23:10:17.287 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - authenticateIfRequired -
                Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2015-01-14_23:10:17.287 DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - decide -
                Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5fcd184d, returned: -1
2015-01-14_23:10:17.298 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - handleSpringSecurityException -
                Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) ~[AffirmativeBased.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) ~[AbstractSecurityInterceptor.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[FilterSecurityInterceptor.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) ~[FilterSecurityInterceptor.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [ExceptionTranslationFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [ExceptionTranslationFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [SessionManagementFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [RequestCacheAwareFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [LogoutFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [HeaderWriterFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [OncePerRequestFilter.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [FilterChainProxy.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [FilterChainProxy.class:3.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [DelegatingFilterProxy.class:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534) [catalina.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring will not inject your AuthenticationEntryPoint automatically even if you annotate it with `@Service`.  You can remove the `@Service` annotation and inject it through your security config like this:

```
http.exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(new MyAuthenticationEntryPoint())
```

Comment: Can you please tell why it will not inject

Comment: But Still my RestExceptionTranslationFilter is not invoked. How to configure it

Comment: I have added     http.addFilter(exceptionTranslationFilter()); but still my custom filter is not invoked

Comment: Your filter is being added at the end of the filter chain, the authentication would happen earlier in the filter chain so it would never have a chance to handle the excption.  Try `http.addFilterAfter(exceptionTranslationFilter(),
        ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)`.  This will add your filter right after the standard `ExceptionTranslationFilter`

Comment: Hi I did try that and still my exception is handled by ExceptionTranslationFilter  instead of my filter, I have added the log, can you please take a look at it

Comment: It is working,  I was adding my filter before ExceptionTranslationFilter , once i added it after, it started to work. I need to read and understand how filter chain works in spring security. Thanks a lot